# How do I upgrade the paserver version 8.0.1.52?

Tags: ios, delphi, paserver

I have paserver version 8.0.1.43 but I should paserver version 8.0.1.52.
How do I upgrade?

Comment: Go to vendor site, download the update, follow the installation instructions? Sounds like business-as-usual, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Copy the file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\PAServer\PAServer16.0.pkg" to your Mac and run it from there.
2. Read the error message that PAServer outputs. It should tell you that the setup for `PAServer16.0.pgk` has been copied to your scratch folder. Open that folder and double click on the setup `PAServer16.0.pgk`.